# Is this is a good approach to share user data between components?

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client, react-hooks

I have **useUserData** hook for getting user data from the server

```
function App({ client }) {
  const data = useUserData({ client })
  console.log(data)
  // logs {username: 'foo', email: 'foo@bar.com'}
  return <AppLayout feed={<Feed />} />
}

export default withApollo(App)
```

hook itself is like this:

```
function useUserData({ client }) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(null)

  const getUserData = async () => {
    const {
      data: { me }
    } = await client.query({
      query: GET_ME
    })
    const { username, email } = me
    setState(me)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserData()
  }, [])

  return state
}
export default useUserData
```

I see I have to use HOC **withApollo** for every component to be able to use the hook. Is this is a good approach?

Comment: you aren't sharing user data between components, also why do you need withApollo HOC to use hook

Comment: well, I can access `data` in App component now. This is just an example. I need withApollo from `react-apollo` to access `client`

Comment: if you call useUserData in all the components, you aren't actually sharing the data that you fetched, instead fetching it in everycomponent, that you called useUserData

Comment: this was my concern. But doesn't it reads from the cache if the query has been already fetched? What's the better approach than this?

Comment: Not sure what Apollo does, but definitely you should use useContext, after you fetch and store the data in the Provider